# how to create scoring system in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

How to create scoring system for the exercise in flash and the score will appears only at the end of the questions?I really hope that you can help me with give the coding that are needed and the full step to create this system in flash.All your helps I really appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic steps to make the simple score system. If there's anything not clear in this tutorial, then please, do no hesitate to ask for further assistance.

**TUTORIAL**

1. On your first frame, you will need to declare a variable which will contain the score and increase it as you progress in the flash file (which is presume is a quiz). So, on your first frame, press F9 to open Actions Panel and type this:

   ```
   score = 0;
   ```
2. Now, whenever you answer a question correctly, use this code to increase the score variable by one:

   ```
   score++;
   ```

   The variable you declared on Frame 1, `score = 0;`, has the value of `0` at start. Now, when you use the code provided above, after the user answers a question correct, `score++;`, you increase the original variable by 1. So, after you use the code above ONE time, your score variable will have the value `1`. Next time you increase the variable, it will have the value `2`, next time again, `3`, and so on. So, this one variable you declared on the first frame will be increased as the user answers the questions correctly. This will NOT be displayed in your flas file, but will be increased in the "computer".
3. When you want to display the score at the end, make a text field, select it, press CTRL+F3 to open up the Properties Panel, and give it an `Instance Name` name of, **score_txt**. Then, use this code on the frame where you have that text field:

   ```
   score_txt.text = score;
   ```

   This will show the value of the variable `score` in the text field `score_txt`.
4. ***Additional Note:*** *This tutorial assumes that you're using the `score++;` on the Main Timeline. If you want to call it from inside a MovieClip, then you have to use instead: `_root.score++;`. If you want to be on the safe side, then change all the codes I've given above, to these:*

   `_root.score = 0;`

   `_root.score++;`

   `score_txt.text = _root.score;`

I hope this helps :)